# Did I kill my Aloe Plant?

Tags: frost

I forgot my aloe plants were on my porch so they were exposed to winter temperatures, with a couple of those nights being below freezing. I brought them in, lightly watered them and they did not bounce back. I cut the leaves all the way down and just read that I probably should not have done that. These are my first aloe plants and I have had them for about 4 years. I am hoping they can be saved and even though leaves will not grow in the same spots that I will still get some new leaves or pups? Please help! I am so upset with myself.

Comment: Also, when I cut the leaves there was an awful smell.

Comment: Samantha, please post some pictures.  Thank you.

Comment: 31°F (-0.5°C) or 24°F (-4°C)? Some plants will handle light, but not hard frost. Aloe tends to get all squishy if it melts after you freeze it. That usually means it's dead, but roots *may* survive. Having cut the leaves, I'd treat the roots nicely for a month or two before tossing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the leaves of a succulent plant is to store water. If the leaves freeze, the ice expanding inside the plant cells will burst the cells and destroy them. You are then left with the outer skin of the leaf full of water and dead plant.

I would say your only hope is to cut them right down to ground level, removing everything that looks or smells damaged, and hope the roots have avoided the frost and will grow again.

But it might be better just to learn from this experience and get some new plants.